# MySQL call the database less times

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 seperate MySQL queries listed below, is there any way of combining them so I can get the same output but just one call to the database (instead of the 3)

Thanks in advance

```
    <?php  
$host   = ''; 
$dbUser = '';   
$dbPass = ''; 
$db = ''; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra1 = '120' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1" ) or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
print "<a href=\"http://www.\" target=\"_new\"> <img src=\"ng\"  border=\"0\" ></a>";
}
?> 
<?php  
$host   = ''; 
$dbUser = '';   
$dbPass = ''; 
$db = ''; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra1 = 'W599_PTO' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1" ) or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
print "<a href=\"php">[?]</FONT></a>";
}
?>
<?php  
$host   = ''; 
$dbUser = '';   
$dbPass = ''; 
$db = ''; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,cat,extra1,extra5,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra5 = '120rear' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1" ) or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
print "<a href=\"09\" target=\"_new\"> <img src=\"http://pg\"  border=\"0\" ert\"></a>";
}
?>
```

I Have now edited the code based on the help provided below...I am a novice at MySQL and am unsure how to set the filter so that any of or all 3 images are displayed based on the value of the 'extra 1' field...

```
    <?php  
$host   = ''; 
$dbUser = '';   
$dbPass = ''; 
$db = ''; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("
SELECT extra1 
FROM pp_photos 
WHERE extra1 IN('1','10','12') 
GROUP BY extra1" ) 
or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
print "<a href=\"h3\" target=\"_new\"> images</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all you don't need to mysql_connect each time.  Secondly, you aren't actually using the values from your $result.  Thirdly, `ORDER BY RAND()` is horrendously slow.   All in all, you really need to rethink what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
$query = "
SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra1 = '120' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra1 = 'W599_PTO' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage FROM pp_photos WHERE extra1 = '120rear' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
";
$cats = array(
    '120'      => '503',
    'W599_PTO' => '508',
    '120rear'  => '509'
);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
    print '<a href="http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/photos/search.php?keywords='.
          $row['extra1'] .
          '&cat=' .
          $cats[$row['extra1']] .
          '" target="_new"><img src="http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/images/camera.png"  border="0" title="photos available"></a>';
}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where would my 'print' "a href =somelink>images</a>";
} condition come into it? - I would like the MySQL to show an image only if the value of "extra1" or "extra5" is matched in the database

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,cat,extra1,bigimage 
FROM pp_photos 
WHERE extra1 IN('W599_PTO','120','120rear') 
GROUP BY extra1
```

This will give you 3 rows. You need to filter according to some condition to get desired row from 3 rows, order by is not required

Comment: Thanks for your reply! While this works, its not doing what it should. Basically, if there is a photo matching W599_PTO then an image is displayed, the same goes for '120 and '120rear' - if there is no photo s that match any of those then no images are displayed. With your answer above, all images are displayed regardless.  Thank you